# Backward slash in JSON response

Tags: json, delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

In JSON response, backward slashes are included in string if we have forward slash character.

I am using the below code to get the API response.

```
procedure GetJSONInformation;
var
  objResponse : TRESTResponse;
  objClient : TRESTClient;
  objRequest : TRESTRequest;
  sJSONResponse : string;
begin
  objResponse  := TRESTResponse.Create(nil);
  objClient := TRESTClient.Create(nil);
  objClient.Accept := 'application/json, text/plain; q=0.9, text/html;q=0.8,';
  objClient.AcceptCharset := 'UTF-8, *;q=0.8';
  objRequest := TRESTRequest.Create(nil);
  objRequest.Method := rmGET;
  objRequest.Accept := 'application/json, text/plain; q=0.9, text/html;q=0.8,';
  objRequest.AcceptCharset := 'UTF-8, *;q=0.8';
  objRequest.Client := objClient;
  objRequest.Response:= objResponse;
  try
    objClient.BaseURL := 'https://sample.net';
    ObjRequest.Resource := 'api/GetInformation/{Param1}/{Param2}';
    ObjRequest.AddParameter('Param1', 'Parameter1', TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkURLSEGMENT);
    ObjRequest.AddParameter('Param2', 'Parameter2', TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkURLSEGMENT);
    ObjRequest.Execute;
    if ObjResponse.StatusCode = 200 then
      sJSONResponse:= ObjResponse.JsonText;  //Here i got the JSON response
  finally
    FreeAndNil(objRequest);
    FreeAndNil(objClient);
    FreeAndNil(objResponse);
  end;
end;
```

In API Response, backward slashes are included in string if I had forward slash in it. For Example,

```
JSON Response:  "Date": "04\/13\/2022",
                "stringdata": "DEC\/ACB test",

Expected Response:  "Date": "04/13/2022",
                    "stringdata": "DEC/ACB test",
```

This is happening only in Alexandria version of Delphi whereas it was working fine in Delphi Berlin.

All I want to remove the backward slash in string. Please help me

Comment: Your question does not seem to make any sense, since you refer to backward slashes, yet your examples have none. It might also help if you include what code you are using to parse the JSON

Comment: You are not showing any code that you used to parse the json. If a json contains a slash it will always add a backslash to "escape it" so when it's parsed the backwards slash gets removed.

Comment: Sorry for the brief note on my question. Here i have explained below.

Comment: Add `sJSONResponse := StringReplace(sJSONResponse, '\/', '/', [rfReplaceAll])` to your code.

Comment: Yes we can resolve it by replace the string but I want to know the reason for adding backslashes and need fix. Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to remove anything.
Just parse valid json response and you will obtain the correct field value without escaped json string, just like  @Dave Nottage and @Adriaan mentioned in comments.

See below two alternatives to parse with System.json and [mORMot](https://synopse.info/files/html/Synopse%20mORMot%20Framework%20SAD%201.18.html). It was tested with Delphi 10.x and Delphi 11 versions.

```
program Test_SystemJson_and_mORMot;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.JSON,
  Syncommons;

const
  ValidJSON='{"Date": "04\/13\/2022","stringdata": "DEC\/ACB test"}';
var
  // with System.JSON
  JsonValue : TJSonValue;
  // with mORMot
  Json : variant;
begin
  // with System.JSON
  JsonValue := TJSonObject.ParseJSONValue(ValidJSON);
  writeln(JsonValue.GetValue<string>('Date')); // Result 04/13/2022
  writeln(JsonValue.GetValue<string>('stringdata')); // Result DEC/ACB test

  // with mORMot
  Json := _Json(ValidJSON);
  writeln(Json.Date); // Result 04/13/2022
  writeln(Json.stringdata); // Result DEC/ACB test
  readln;
end.
```

Answer (score 0):

From Embarcadero Quality portal found a reply by Marco Cantù about this behavior and he mentions can get the JSON raw value by using `TJSONPair.JsonValue.Value`. Tried and seems to work as expected.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).